# Format a string with uppercase

Tags: javascript, string

I have to format a string. So I would like that my string is automatic format well.
For example:
I have this string :

> "hello, my name is Michael. can you help me?i have a problem"

I would like that using JavaScript, the string becomes :

> "Hello, my name is Michael. Can you help me? I have a problem"

So the function for do that have to check the first letter (in this case "h") is capitalize, if there is a space after dots (and add space and capitalize first letter after dot) and in case there is a space check if the first letter is capitalize.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You can google uppercase first letter of each sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex to do that

```js
function formatSentence(sentence) {
  return sentence
    .replace(/^\w/g, function(m) {
      return m.toUpperCase();
    }).replace(/(\.|\?)\s?(\w)/g, function(_, m1, m2) {
      return m1 + ' ' + m2.toUpperCase();
    })
}

document.write(formatSentence("hello, my name is Michael. can you help me?i have a problem"));
```

Comment: Nice! But there is still a space missing: ` me?I have `

Comment: @CodeiSir : Ohhh , I just missed that... let me check :)

Comment: You're the man ;) - match chars `[aZ]` and check if there is a sign just before it and then add the space?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatSentence(sentence) {
  return sentence.replace(/^\w/g, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/(\.|\?)\s?(\w)/g, function(_, m1, m2) {
    return m1 + ' ' + m2.toUpperCase();
  })
}

var sentence = "hello, my name is Michael. can you help me?i have a problem";
setence = formatSentence(sentence);
document.write(setence);
```

I don't want any credit, but here is the function of Pranvan's Code: